# independently scaled services in one heroku app

Tags: ruby, heroku, rack

I can't see anything in the Documentation on the Heroku Cedar stack that indicates this is possible, but I'm wondering if I can use a single codebase on a single Heroku app to mount multiple services (rack apps for instance) that get requests sent to them based on some condition.

I'm looking for something similar to the way I can tell a rack application to mount at a specific `url`.

Ideally, this would allow me to scale these services independently, but use the same codebase, models etc for whatever work it is doing.

For instance, I might have an `api` service that just handles api calls.  This could be a simple rack application that should have fast response time and be able to scale itself independently of the web application that serves the main site.  It could either use the same domain with a particular path, or use a different domain that somehow gets mapped to a rack application running on some specific port.

Anyone know if this type of things is possible?  I know the alternatives (gemifying my code and sharing amongst different applications) but I'm exploring this as a possibility first.

Comment: What does it mean to scale up a service in this case? I would have thought about it like adding a dyno, but that obviously affects all services. Anyway, I don't know a lot about rack, so not sure how mounting works, but it would be trivial to write a rack app as the endpoint that just looks at the url and then invokes the rack app (ie it's a lambda with a case statement that just forwards the invocation based on something like `env['HTTP_HOST']`)

Comment: I think with the standard Heroku offering, scalability is set purely at the app level.  I doubt there is a way to scale this within the app without heroku intervention (but at the right price point, who knows?).  Please answer your own question if you get a definitive answer from Heroku.

Comment: ya i basically mean scaling with a dyno.  The new Cedar stack allows you to scale processes in such a way using a [Procfile](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile), so I could define an `api` process for instance and add more dynos to it.  What I don't know how to do, is route web traffic to it.

Comment: Bear in mind you only have one external $PORT per application that others can connect to, so you'd need to figure out how to work around this.

Comment: that's kind of the point of my question.

Comment: OK - you cannot bind more than process to a single port.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do this?  If you deploy the same code to multiple applications on Heroku, you can share your code, scale them individually, give them different endpoint URLs AND get 750 hours free per app per month.

What you're suggesting sounds complex and error-prone so keep it simple.

If you're needing to share a database between them, then that's fine too: http://neilmiddleton.com/sharing-databases-between-heroku-applications/

Comment: I think what I'm suggesting would actually be simpler.  I could just define a Rack app within my rails app, then mount it separately.  It could load `ActiveRecord` for db work, but doesn't need the whole Rails stack so it should be fast.  Your way I'd have to maintain gems and ensure that my deploys are sync'd so as to avoid issues with migrations, out of date code etc...

Comment: Fair enough.  I'm just saying I've deployed hundreds of applications to Heroku, and I wouldn't go near your method.

Comment: Ya so it seems what i wanted to do is not available.  So... if we were to use the same codebase to two different apps.  Do you just set certain config vars that determine what Rack app to launch?  ie `ENV['RACKUP'] = 'api.ru'`

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the best way of doing it.

Comment: cool.  I'll post back with my findings.  Will mark your answer correct assuming everything works well on my end.  Thx a bunch